# sql to get events that your friends are attending

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a few tables

```
    User (UserId)
    Event (EventId)
    AttendingEvent (UserId,EventId)
    Friends (UserId,UserId)
```

I want to write a query that can return events where a specific user that I know the id of beforehand has friends that are going to it ordered by the event with the most friends attending.

Comment: "I want to write a query" - what's stopping you? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  In the future try to do some research first or at least show some attempt towards a solution to avoid downvotes.  Please mark as answer if this helps.

This will return the events that your friends are attending, in order by the number of friends attending.

```
WITH TheEventsCounted as (SELECT EventId, Count(UserId) FROM AttendingEvent WHERE UserId IN
(SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE MyUserId = @ID)
GROUP BY EventId)   

SELECT * FROM Event   
WHERE EventId IN TheEventsCounted
ORDER BY Num
```